# Declare NavGraph built with Kotlin DSL in NavDeepLinkBuilder

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to create a deep link that will be used when the user presses a push notification. Previously I did something like that:

```kotlin
NavDeepLinkBuilder(application)
    .setComponentName(MyActivity::class.java)
    .setGraph(R.id.my_graph)
    .setDestination(R.id.my_destination, extras)
    .createPendingIntent()
```

After migrating to Kotlin DSL for navigation, I do not have any XML. So I need to create programmatically the graph.

```kotlin
val myGraph = // somehow build it
NavDeepLinkBuilder(application)
    .setComponentName(MyActivity::class.java)
    .setGraph(R.id.my_graph)
    .setDestination(R.id.my_destination, extras)
    .createPendingIntent()
```

In order to create the graph and add it to my `Activity`'s `NavController` I use the `NavController`'s `createGraph` function. So I do something like that:

```kotlin
fun NavController.myGraph(): NavGraph = createGraph("starting_destination") {
    // add Destinations. Destinations can be other NavGraphs too. 
    // Which means that call to similar functions may be made.
    // Functions like this one:
    // 
    // fun NavController.myGraph2(): NavGraph = createGraph("starting_destination2") {}

}
```

In the `FirebaseMessagingService` I do not have a `NavController`. How is it possible to get the graph that is created by the `myGraph` function? In `NavDeepLinkBuilder`'s source code I found that I can use  `NavigatorProvider` and build the graph but this seems to replicate the whole logic and having to maintain the graph in two places...